# CppCheck + CMake - skip thirdparty sources

Tags: c++, cmake, cppcheck

I am working on a large codebase consisting of Modern C++, Legacy C++ (30+ years old MFC) and a number of third-party libraries (Boost, RangeV3, Catch2 etc.).

The code is built using **CMake** and targeted to Windows and Linux (x86 & ARM).
For the modern code I am using **CppCheck** for static analysis. Unfortunately when I build with **CppCheck** enabled a lot of time is spent running **CppCheck** over the third-party source (*.cpp) files.

The thirdparty sources are included via the **CMake** `FethContent` syntax, e.g.

```
Include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  Catch2
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git
  GIT_TAG        v3.0.1
  SYSTEM
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Catch2)
```

**CppCheck** is enabled via:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK
                       --suppress=missingInclude
                       --suppress=missingIncludeSystem
                       --suppress=unusedFunction
                       --suppress=unmatchedSuppression
                       --suppress=functionStatic
                       --suppress=funcArgNamesDifferent
                       --suppress=*:*_deps/*
                       --enable=all
                       --inline-suppr
                       --inconclusive
                       --force
                       -i ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/imgui/lib
                       )
```

The `_deps` directory is the location where thirdparty sources are fetched and built and the line `--suppress=*:*_deps/*` disables **CppCheck** for the headers but does not prevent it from running when each thirdparty library is built.

**How can I prevent CppCheck from being run over the thirdparty libraries?**

Is there something I can add to the **CMake** section which pulls in the library to disable it? Such as clearing `CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK` before the call to `FetchContent_Declare` and setting it again after the call `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`

Comment: `-i` doesn't work for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Such as clearing CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK before the call to FetchContent_Declare and setting it again after the call FetchContent_MakeAvailable

That's the best way to do it to prevent cmake from running Cppcheck on sources you don't want it to.

Try this:

```
set(old_cmake_cxx_cppcheck "${CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK "")
// FetchContent stuff here...
set(CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK "${old_cmake_cxx_cppcheck")
```

Comment: I ended up with something similar, which appears to work, the only difference is the use of `unset(CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK)` to clear it...

Comment: I think you'll still want to `--suppress=*:*_deps/*` if you want to suppress warnings from the third party headers your codebase includes.

Comment: I am keeping all the options ... I jusr don't want it running over third party cpp files.